# (JAVA) Print a table displaying numbers from 1-10 that print the number, its cube root, square root, square root, square, and cube

Tags: java

Print a table of the numbers from 1 to 10 displaying in a tabular fashion the number, its cube root, square root, square, and cube.

Here is the desired output:
[image]

My code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
                    System.out.printf("%6d", i, Math.cbrt(i) + " " + Math.sqrt(i) + " " + (i * i) + " " + (i * i * i));
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
}
```

My code gives the output:

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6     6     6
 7     7     7     7     7     7
 8     8     8     8     8     8
 9     9     9     9     9     9
10    10    10    10    10    10
```

Can anyone help me get the right output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use different format specifiers for printing floating points and integers.

Also, in `System.out.printf()`, you can separate the values using comma `,`. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

`%d` - for integers

`%f` - for floating points

`%.6f` - for floating points with 6 digits of precision

Also, I removed the extra nested for loop, it was unnecessary.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d %.6f %.6f %d %d\n", i, Math.cbrt(i), Math.sqrt(i), (i * i), (i * i * i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is obviously a class assignment I will just give you a hint.
You are generally creating a long string to feed into the printf method and asking it to format it as a number.

The printf method can handle many arguments (vararg) as well, so either feed line by line with many arguments or separate into one printf call for each calculation.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf#2-float-and-double-formatting

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)